Certification of high voltage to low voltage converters
Does anyone have any experience with certification of high voltage to low voltage power converters designed with COTS DC-DC controllers for eVTOL or MEA applications?
I am interested to know about the process and if its possible to use such COTS controllers and obtain a certification.

DC to DC static converters used in avionics (communication/navigation equipment) are approved against technical specifications in a Technical Standard Order (TSO):

TSO C71 by FAA,
ETSO C71 by EASA.

This TSO details values for elements like regulation rate, ripple, over-voltage, short circuit response, RF emissions, temperature range, etc.
More information (FAA):

TSO authorization
FAA process in Part 21.

In the latter process, 21.603 states:

(a) An applicant for a TSO authorization must apply in the form and manner prescribed by the FAA. The applicant must include the following documents in the application:

(1) A statement of conformance certifying that the applicant has met the requirements of this subpart and that the article concerned meets the applicable TSO that is effective on the date of application for that article.
(2) One copy of the technical data required in the applicable TSO.


After reviewing data required by the TSO, FAA and EASA deliver a Letter of TSO Authorization (TSOA), a model is provided in AC 8150, mentioning:

This is in reply to your letter of {enter date of application} requesting TSO authorization for your {insert type of article}. We accept your statement certifying that your article meets the
requirements of TSO-C {enter applicable TSO number} and that you meet the requirements of Title 14, Code of Federal Regulations (14 CFR) part 21, subpart O.


The FAA TSO C-71 is available on the FAA.gov website

Thanks. C71 refers to input voltages up to 28V only though. Can C71 be used for high voltage inputs like 270V, 540V or 800V?

@SSA: No this TSO only applies to a DC-DC converter used in navigation/communication equipment, not to HVDC converters. Unfortunately I'm not aware of HVDC related regulations.

My understanding is the certification is still done to the TSO, but with a deviation for the voltage level
